# Can seem to bring down docker containers

Tags: docker

I run docker ps and it shows that 5 containers that have been running for three weeks.
I then run docker-compose down but when I run docker ps again, they are all still running.
I have tried the following command but none seems to work
kill
stop
down --rmi local
rm
down

How can I stop these? I tried just bringing up my new docker-compose.yml and ignoring the olde one but I get:
ERROR: for apache  Cannot create container for service apache: Conflict. The container name "/apache" is already in use by container "70c570d60e1248292f279a37634fd8b4ce7e2535d2bfa14b2c6e4089652c0152". You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

What to try to stop the old container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list containers:

```
(base) docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                                       NAMES
c788727f0f7b   postgres:14   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 days ago   Up 7 days   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   dev-db
88e8ddcb7d4e   redis         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 days ago   Up 7 days   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp   beautiful_neumann
```

Delete container:

```
(base) docker rm -f c788727f0f7b # container_id
c788727f0f7b
```

List containers:

```
(base) docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED      STATUS      PORTS                                       NAMES
88e8ddcb7d4e   redis     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 days ago   Up 7 days   0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp, :::6379->6379/tcp   beautiful_neumann
```

As you can see the container got stopped(`c788727f0f7b`).

You can list stopped containers using:

```
docker container ls -f 'status=exited'
```

Comment: docker rm -f worked great. Thx!